# Stop other mediaplayers when webview starts playing media in android

Tags: android, audio, video, webview

I am showing a web page in webview which includes a video. What I need is a way to know when the video streaming starts in the webview? I need to do something when this happens. Is there some kind of event or notification etc. available for this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be a little bit more descriptive in question.

Comment: I am showing a web page in webview which includes a video. What I need is a way to know when the video streaming starts in the webview? I need to do something when this happens. Is there some kind of event or notification etc. available for this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe there. It will be easy for other to find out your problem and provide their help. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you Ariful for your advice.